# Operator "-" cannot be applied to operands "string" and "double" C#

Tags: c#

While working on a calculator i was attempting to use strings and doubles from a textbox to get the answer and got this error when working on the subtraction, multiplication, division and, exponents :

> "Operator "-" cannot be applied to operands "string" and "double""

**Code :**

```
private void BtnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OperationLbl.Text = "";
    switch (operation)
    {
        case "+":
            textBox1.Text = (results + Double.Parse(textBox1.Text).ToString());
            break;
        case "-":
            textBox1.Text = (results - Double.Parse(textBox1.Text).ToString());
            break;
        case "*":
            textBox1.Text = (results * Double.Parse(textBox1.Text).ToString());
            break;
        case "/":
            textBox1.Text = (results / Double.Parse(textBox1.Text).ToString());
            break;
        case "^":
            textBox1.Text = (results ^ Double.Parse(textBox1.Text).ToString());
            break;
    }
}
```

After attempting to tinker around and work around this error, i couldn't do it efficiently. So if you could please stick to the case that would be great, if not i understand.

Comment: What is `results`?

Comment: It seems your `results` is a string type variable. Isnt it??

Comment: @Steve Nope its a double

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Nope its a double

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance to provide code samples. In this case sample should be `string s = (1d * 1d.ToString());` and not wall of code in current post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : thanks for mentioning; I have fixed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this (and the ones like it)

```
 (results + Double.Parse(textBox1.Text).ToString());
```

should be:

```
 (results + Double.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
```

You are parsing the text to a double and then immediately calling ToString() converting it back to a string.  You need to place the ToString() at the end to convert the result to a string.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, and i also got the Exponent to work with a little of tinkering

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `results` is a `double`, then it's bracket placement:

```
textBox1.Text = (results + Double.Parse(textBox1.Text).ToString());
```

should be:

```
textBox1.Text = (results + Double.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that error message is self explaining, You know that the variable `result` is of type double and the error message stated that `"Operator "-" cannot be applied to operands "string" and "double""` So it is understood that the second operand is string,  from that you can conclude that `.ToString()` creates the issues here. I would like to suggest a different fix for you; you can do something like this:

```
double currentNumber;
if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out currentNumber))
{
    switch (operation)
    {
        case "+":
            textBox1.Text = (results + currentNumber).ToString();
            break;
        case "-":
            textBox1.Text = (results - currentNumber).ToString();
            break;
        case "*":
            textBox1.Text = (results * currentNumber).ToString();
            break;
        case "/":
            textBox1.Text = (results / currentNumber).ToString();
            break;
        case "^":
            textBox1.Text = (results ^ currentNumber).ToString();
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    textBox1.Text = "Invalid input";            
}
```

Since `Double.Parse` may throw `FormatException` in case of invalid input, to avoid that you can go ahead with `TryParse` as i suggested.

Comment: Hope that the person downvoted this post have some personal revenge, Because I can say that ;-  1. TryParse is always better than Parse(in other two answers). 2. Have little more explanation than other two

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `ToString` on the returned value of `Double.Parse`. I'm pretty sure you wanted to call `ToString` on the result of the arithmetic operation but you got your parenthesis wrong.